# Access remote IP address in resource server proxied through Zuul and Apache

Tags: apache, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

For a security check I need access to the user's remote IP address in my resource service. This resource service is a simple recent Spring Boot app, that registers itself with my Eureka server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
    }
}
```

All services registered with my Eureka server are dynamically routed through my Zuul routing proxy server based on Angel.SR3 `starter-zuul` and `starter-eureka`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
public class RoutingProxyServer {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingProxyServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Zuul routing proxy server also configures an AJP connector for the next step:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("ajp.port")
public class TomcatAjpConfig extends TomcatWebSocketContainerCustomizer {
    @Value("${ajp.port}")
    private int port;

    @Override
    public void doCustomize(final TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat) {
        super.doCustomize(tomcat);

        // Listen for AJP requests
        Connector ajp = new Connector("AJP/1.3");
        ajp.setPort(port);
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(ajp);
    }
}
```

All requests to the dynamic routing zuul proxy are proxied themselves through Apache to provide HTTPS on the standard 443 port:

```
# Preserve Host when proxying so jar apps return working URLs in JSON responses
RequestHeader           set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
ProxyPreserveHost   On
# Redirect remaining traffic to routing proxy server
ProxyPass       /       ajp://192.168.x.x:8009/
# Also update Location, Content-Location and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses
ProxyPassReverse    /       ajp://192.168.x.x:8009/
```

With all  this in place the resource service is made available, but unfortunately the remoteAddress that I get from Spring Security is the address of the Zuul proxy/Apache server, not the remote client IP address.

In the past I had used a `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource` that preferred the `X-Forwarded-For` header value over the normal `remoteAddress` to get the correct IP address, but I can not work out how to pass the proper remote IP address to my resource service when passing through two proxies (Apache + Zuul).

Can anyone help me access the correct remote IP address behind these two proxies, or suggest an alternative approach to get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the X-Forwarded-For header was taken from the original request feeding into Zuul to populate `HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`. This would then have to be passed on to the proxied backend services through `RequestContext#getZuulRequestHeaders().put("X-Forwarded-For", remoteAddr)`. The following `ZuulFilter` accomplishes this, even if it isn't appending it's own value to the `X-Forwarded-For` filter just yet.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class XForwardedForFilter extends ZuulFilter {
private static final String X_FORWARDED_FOR = "X-Forwarded-For";

@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    // Rely on HttpServletRequest to retrieve the correct remote address from upstream X-Forwarded-For header
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
    String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

    // Pass remote address downstream by setting X-Forwarded for header again on Zuul request
    log.debug("Settings X-Forwarded-For to: {}", remoteAddr);
    ctx.getZuulRequestHeaders().put(X_FORWARDED_FOR, remoteAddr);

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 10000;
}
}
```

One might want to clear the header value in Apache before proxying to Zuul to prevent accepting just any value provided by the user: `RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For`

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you can use servletRequest.getRemoteAddr() to get the client’s IP address that’s accessing your Java web application.

```
String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

But, if user is behind a proxy server or access your web server through a load balancer (for example, in cloud hosting), the above code will get the IP address of the proxy server or load balancer server, not the original IP address of a client.

To solve it, you should get the IP address of the request’s HTTP header “X-Forwarded-For (XFF)“.

```
   String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
   if (ipAddress == null) {  
       ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
   }
```

Comment: That's what I did before I added Zuul, but that approach no longer works. The headers are not passed and/or I get the proxy server address. See second to last paragraph.